# How can I increment this number each time the page is accessed?

Tags: php

In this example, the first invoice number should be 2015-001; this works fine but now I want to increase it every time the page is accessed.

```
$Datum = Date("Y");
$Teken = "-";
$num = 1;


echo $Datum, $Teken;
printf("%03d", $num);
```

Comment: Learn Javascript! [**Here is what you want!**](http://www.jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @Rizier123, that's probably not what they want if they want the number to increment server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a number of different ways. Saving it in a session, a cookie, even to a database. You could do it in JavaScript, PHP or other languages, but as you asked for PHP, we'll do it in that.

I'll show you two ways to do it in PHP, first:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['num'])){
  $_SESSION['num'] += 1;
} else {
  $_SESSION['num'] = 1;
}
```

Second:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['num'])){
  $_COOKIE['num'] += 1;
} else {
  $_COOKIE['num'] = 1;
}
```

The second code is similar to the first in how it looks, just without `session_start();`.

Then you can use it like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['num'])){
  $_SESSION['num'] += 1;
} else {
  $_SESSION['num'] = 1;
}

$Datum = Date("Y");
$Teken = "-";
$num = $_SESSION['num'];


echo $Datum, $Teken;
printf("%03d", $num);
```

Comment: Thanks BeatAlex it is exactly very simple